# How to use easeljs in redux

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, redux, createjs, easeljs

I want to play multiple sprite animation in redux (ES6). I am using npm createjs-easeljs library. I did npm install createjs-easeljs and calling as import createjs from 'createjs-easeljs'. I am getting error as Uncaught ReferenceError: createjs is not defined. I want to use easeljs for sprite animation in redux. What is the right way of using it. Sorry if my question is silly actually I am new to react-redux.

Answer (score 2):

it is not redux problem. I have tested this npm module, it won't work;

**there are ways**

[related issue on github with wepack/bower solution](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues/713)

[CDN easeljs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/EaselJS)